# Bootstap 4 Modal - Execute anonymous function while trigering the modal

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a Bootstrap 4 Modal in a partial which is called in different context. I want to trigger it and add different data attributes depending on the context.

Something like this (obviously this is not working):

```
<!-- Context 1 -->
$("#sameModal").modal("show", function () {
   $(this).data("foo", true);
});
```

```
<!-- Context 2 -->
$("#sameModal").modal("show", function () {
   $(this).data("foo", false);
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The modal event `show.bs.modal` is useful in this case, which will be triggered when the modal show event is triggered. Check out the below snippet which attaches data `foo` to modal with this modal event. Check out documentation for [modal events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events)

```js
$(function () {
    setModalEvents();
});
function setModalEvents() {
    // Set event on modal shown
    $("#exampleModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $(this).find('.modal-body').html('foo value: <b>' + $(this).data('foo') + "</b>");
    });

    // Context 1 event
    $("#contentOneBtn").on('click', function () {
        $("#exampleModal")
            // To set one time event before modal show is triggered
            .one('show.bs.modal', function () {
                $(this).data("foo", true);
            })
            .modal('show');
    });

    // Context 2 event
    $("#contentTwoBtn").on('click', function () {
        $("#exampleModal")
            // To set one time event before modal show is triggered
            .one('show.bs.modal', function () {
                $(this).data("foo", false);
            })
            .modal('show');
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>BT4 Modal Demo!</title>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button id="contentOneBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin: 15px;">
        Launch demo modal Context One
    </button>
    <button id="contentTwoBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin: 15px;">
        Launch demo modal Context One
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```